# What is the Raphael.js equivalent to JQuerys $(this) selector?

Tags: javascript, raphael, css-selectors

When I'm inside a click event I want to run the function on that single Raphael element such as a circle. How can I target that individual element and not all the circles on the page?

JQuery selector - `$(this).animate({ opacity: 0.2}, 2000);`

I need to know what the equivalent of `$(this)` is. Or if there is another way of selecting that element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attach an event using Raphael itself, `this` is the Raphael wrapped element (i.e. `this` is by default the equivalent of $(selector)).

For example

```
paper.rect(50, 50, 50, 50)
    .attr('fill', '#000')
    .click(function () {
        // `this` is the rect Raphael object
        this.attr('fill', '#ff0000');  // turn the clicked rect red
    });
```

To implement the jQuery-style wrapper a weak map implementation is required and these tend to leak. It's best to use the Raphael api for attaching events to the SVG elements than attaching events to the nodes directly.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FyM7z/

Comment: thanks for the information, I will take this on board and go and do some research. At least your answer wasn't condescending like @elclanrs was.

Comment: It wasn't my intention but I do agree this answer is better.

Comment: its cool dont worry. day 2 of learning raphael, insanely fun I must admit.

Comment: Yeah it's a great library, just started recently too. Indeed, `this` will always be the DOM element inside an event AFAIK.

Comment: this is such a good answer - assigning the click event when creating the element. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`this` just refers to the DOM element in the case of jQuery and can have many contexts. There's no equivalent per say, if you create a new instance of Raphael on a canvas element like `var instance = new Raphael(canvasEl, 100, 100 )` and you want to reference the canvas later you'd have to cache it in a variable and use that throughout the code.

If you're creating paths with Raphael and want to store them, assign them to a variable like  `var square = raphaelCanvas.rect(20,20,20,20)`.